# Three.js animate absarc using tweenjs

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween, tweenjs

I am currently creating a pie chart in three.js by calling this function multiple times, which creates for each data one segment and passes the starting angle and the end angle for the specific segment.

```
createSegment(radius, angleStart, angleEnd) {
    let extrudeOptions = {
        curveSegments: 50,
        steps: 1,
        amount: 1.0,
        bevelEnabled: false,
    };

    let shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape.moveTo(0, 0);
    shape.absarc(0, 0, radius, angleStart, angleEnd, false); //false: to not go clockwise (otherwise it will fail)
    shape.lineTo(0, 0);
    let segmentGeom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeOptions);
    let segmentMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        specular: 0xffffff,
        shininess: 1.0,
    });

    return new THREE.Mesh(segmentGeom, segmentMat);
}
```

I would like to animate the drawing of the `shape` with tween.js, but I don't know how I could use the tween easing instead of the absarc, which is drawing the segment? Is it possible to set the absarc at the beginning to zero and then draw inside the tween?

In order to give you an idea of what animation I am thinking of, check out this site and the animation here http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/
I want the pie chart to draw each segment one by one. At the moment, the pie chart gets drawn and is instantly rendered, so no animations.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a gif or an image of the animation you are thinking about? I can think of multiple ways you might want this to appear.

Comment: @spirulence I have edited the question. You can find a link to some animated 2D graphs. I want to achieve the exact same animation, just in 3D. Its only the question how to use the tween.js library and the THREE.Shape() to animate the drawing.

Comment: @Bajaro Suggestion: Instead, create individual 3D pie slices and use tween to animate the depth of each by changing `mesh.scale.z`from 0.01 to 1. Also start each slice with `mesh.visible = false`, and make them appear one-by-one. That should be a nice 3D effect -- and it is easily doable.

Comment: @WestLangley with the createSegment function, I am already creating my individual segments (slices) of my pie chart. the createSegment is calles in my other function which gets the data as json and then calculates the starting angle and end angle and passes it to this function.

Comment: @Bajro I know that. I am suggesting that you consider a different animation that is easily doable -- use tween to animate the thickness of each slice, instead of the angle. It is up to you.

Comment: @WestLangleyYeah I think I have to stick to some other tactics. I tried to set the absarc function into the tween.onUpdate function but that didn't worked as you have to draw the shape before adding it to the ExtrudeGeometry, the mesh and finally into the scene.

Comment: @WestLangley What would be if I try to draw a very thin segment and then animate the drawing by setting the vertices to dynamic and updating them?

Comment: @Bajro That would work, as long as the number of vertices does not change. You would need to set the `needsUpdate` flag and update normals, too. I do not think 'dynamic' is relevant.

Comment: @WestLangley Okay I would try that out with the vertices. Even though I already tried it out once, but maybe I did something wrong. Btw, what do you mean "as long as the number of the vertices does not change"? You mean the length of the vertices or the actual x,y and z values of them? I think you mean the length, so that no new vertices are added?